How to assign values to points based on nearest next point in R?
I have a dataset with X and Y coordinates and a column indicating certain values.
Looking something like this:
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                 X=c(420729, 420329, 518020, 518013, 517620, 517604, 518024),
                 Y=c(32072, 32032, 41802, 41801, 41762, 41760, 41802),
                 value=c(123, 42, NA, 22, NA, 55, 43))

For the points with NA's in the value column I want to assign the value from the point that is closest to it.
I managed to find the closest point by using the nn2 function from the RANN package, but to do that I had to delete the value column:
df1 <- subset(data, select=-c(value)) 

closest <- nn2(data=d1f, k=2)[[1]]

closest

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4    3
[5,]    5    6
[6,]    6    5
[7,]    7    3


Okay, now I know the closest point for the points that have NA values, how now to assign the values from the closest neighbor to those points? Also, what if the closest point also has an NA values, is there a way to do this in a more straightforward way where I specify to look at points that don't have NA in the value column to end up with this dataframe:
df3 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                 X=c(420729, 420329, 518020, 518013, 517620, 517604, 518024),
                 Y=c(32072, 32032, 41802, 41801, 41762, 41760, 41802),
                 value=c(123, 42, 43, 22, 55, 55, 43))


cols <- c('X', 'Y')
idx1 <- is.na(df$value)
idx2 <- c(RANN::nn2(df[!idx1, cols], df[idx1,cols], 1)$nn.idx)
df$value[idx1] <- df$value[!idx][idx2]
df

  ID      X     Y value
1  1 420729 32072   123
2  2 420329 32032    42
3  3 518020 41802    43
4  4 518013 41801    22
5  5 517620 41762    55
6  6 517604 41760    55
7  7 518024 41802    43

